# Expressing forces in Pendulum swing in component form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am finding it difficult to understand how the following forces in a pendulum swing are derived. Given the following info about a pendulum angle = $\theta$, Mass = m and length of string is L and the forces acting on the pendulum are Tension, Weight and the restoring/gravitational force. My questions are how is the restoring force expressed as -mg $\sin\theta$ and how would you express the Tension force in this form? Thanks for your help.

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

There are two forces acting on the bob, Tension acting in the direction of the string and Weight $W=mg$ acting downwards.

Assuming the string stays taught and does not change in length, you can infer that the Tension must exactly balance the component of the weight in the direction of the string.

So

$$ T = mg\cos\theta $$

The net force on the bob must be perpendicular to the direction of the string, so.

$$F_{net}=-mg\sin\theta $$

Comment: Thanks for the response, how did you arrive at $$T = mg\cos\theta $$ I know that $mg$ is the weight ? From that derivation of the tension vector and as the restoring force is perpendicular to the tension vector would I be correct is saying it would then be $$mg\cos\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$$ which would then be $$mg\sin\theta$$? Have another question here if I am correct why the minus sign before the sin function?

Comment: $$\vec F_{net}=-mg\sin\theta \; \hat \theta$$

where $\hat \theta$ is the unit vector in the direction of increasing $\theta$